# Why am i getting segmentation fault when passing a pointer as a function parameter?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, parameter-passing, bison

I build an AST with bison with a pointer to a *Node* structure:

```
typedef struct Node {
    enum node_type type;
    Stmt *left;
    struct Node *right;
} Node;
```

Then I print it in bison in this manner:

```
printf("%s\n",root->right->left->value_s.declaration->value_d.string);
printf("%s\n",root->right->left->value_s.declaration->id);
printf("%s\n",root->right->right->right->left->value_s.stdout->string);
```

it shows well, but I was trying to print it with an external function and then I get the segmentation fault. This is the starter bison production:

```
program: stmts { 
        printf("---- PRINTING AST ----\n");
        $$ =  malloc(sizeof(Node));
        $$->type = NODE_TYPE_NODE;
        $$->left = NULL;
        $$->right = $1;
        Traversal($$);
        }
;
```

This is the code of the external function:

```
void Traversal(struct Node *root) {
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        printf("AST is empty.");
    else {
        switch (root->left->type) {        
        case NODE_TYPE_STMT_D:
            TravDeclaration(root->left->value_s.declaration);
            break;
        /* other cases */
        default:
            printf("Error, check node_type.");
            break;
        }
        if(root->right->type != NODE_TYPE_END)
            Traversal(root->right);
    }
}
```

I think that there is a possible error in the use of the pointer when I call the external function. Please tell me if I missed something in the question, this is my first time here.

Comment: `$` is a non-standard character.  Some compilers allow it, but it is not good practice to use it in a variable name.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, dollars are bison special characters. I will use named references as explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Named-References). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @glatrofa Ah!  I didn't see that was bison.  Carry on.  I've too often stumbled across C code that used variable names which included `$`, and I thought you were literally using the name `$$`.  It sent a shiver down my spine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switch (root->left->type)
```

If `root->left` is `NULL` (which it is in this case because you set `$$->left = NULL;`) and `root->right` is not, the above line will dereference a `NULL` pointer.

Similarly your later use of `root->right->type` would dereference `NULL` in the case where `root->right` is `NULL` and `root->left` is not.

Comment: Yes, solved with `Traversal($$->right)`. Thanks!